# how can I extract year from a column in python. the data is in this form: 'October 1, 2020 (United States)'?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a different approach but nothing is working as I can't slice the text as the month fields have variable length.

I tried slicing and extracting as well, but it makes a new dataframe and makes the code longer because then I have to split the column first, extract the year, and then concatenate the values back to the dataframe.

Comment: Use the `.str.extract()` method with a regular expression that matches the year.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split()` to turn it into a list. You can grab the year and convert it into an int from there.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['October 1 2022 (United States)']})

df['year'] = int(df['date'].str.split()[0][2])
```

Output:

```
                          date  year
October 1 2022 (United States)  2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex and [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['year'] = df['date'].str.extract(r'(?P<Year>\d{4}(?=(?:\s+\()))')

df

                             date  year
0  October 1 2022 (United States)  2022
```

The regular expression I used matches values with similar pattern to your sample date. In case they differ in patterns we could use more flexible regex.